# android croped image is too small

Tags: android, image, crop

I am using image cropper app in android devices to crop image from **camera** or **gallery**

Images will Convert To String  And will send to server
so on server, image size is **160X160**, Device is **Samsung GALAXY Tab2 10.1**

Whats Wrong on used code?

Resize Code To Show Thumb return **120X120** Image And **Not Send Thumb To Server**

```
private String setBitmapToString(Bitmap bmp) {
    String base64String = null;
    if (bmp == null) {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                R.drawable.app_icon);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imgBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    base64String = Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes,
            Base64.DEFAULT);

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put("picture", base64String);

    // save your base64String to DB
    return base64String;
}
```

i am using the following method to Take Picture Or Pick it up From Device And finally Crop:

```
//==================== Take Picture
ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
private Bitmap photo;
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE   = 3;
private void takePicture(){
    final String[] items = new String[]{App.context.getString(R.string.SELECT_FROM_CAMERA), App.context.getString(R.string.SELECT_FROM_GALLERY)};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("انتخاب تصویر");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { //pick from camera
            if (item == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else { //pick from file
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, App.context.getString(R.string.Complete_action_using)), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    rlImage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastSelect = 1;
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    rlImage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastSelect = 2;
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    rlImage3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastSelect = 3;
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    rlImage4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastSelect = 4;
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    txtSelectLogoNj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastSelect = 5;
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
private int lastSelect = 4;
String image1 = "", image2 = "", image3 = "", image4 = "", image5 = "";
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            doCrop();
            break;
        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            doCrop();
            break;
        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                int w = (int) (UIHelpers.width * 0.15);
                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
                if (f.exists()) {
                    //f.delete();
                }
                Log.d("TakePicture", "File Path : " + f.getAbsolutePath() + " , Size : " + w);
                switch (lastSelect){
                    case 5:
                        txtSelectLogoNj.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        rlLogoNj.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        image5 = ""+setBitmapToString(photo);
                        App.sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(App.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        App.editor = App.sharedpreferences.edit();
                        App.editor.putString("IMAGE5", image5);
                        App.editor.commit();
                        imgLogoNj.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, w, false));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        image4 = ""+setBitmapToString(photo);
                        App.sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(App.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        App.editor = App.sharedpreferences.edit();
                        App.editor.putString("IMAGE4", image4);
                        App.editor.commit();
                        imgImage4.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, w, false));
                        txtImage4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        image3 = ""+setBitmapToString(photo);
                        App.sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(App.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        App.editor = App.sharedpreferences.edit();
                        App.editor.putString("IMAGE3", image3);
                        App.editor.commit();
                        imgImage3.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, w, false));
                        txtImage3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        image2 = ""+setBitmapToString(photo);
                        App.sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(App.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        App.editor = App.sharedpreferences.edit();
                        App.editor.putString("IMAGE2", image2);
                        App.editor.commit();
                        imgImage2.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, w, false));
                        txtImage2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        image1 = ""+setBitmapToString(photo);
                        App.sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(App.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        App.editor = App.sharedpreferences.edit();
                        App.editor.putString("IMAGE1", image1);
                        App.editor.commit();
                        imgImage1.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, w, false));
                        txtImage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;

    }
}
private void doCrop() {
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.crop_unavailable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // return
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", UIHelpers.width);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", UIHelpers.width);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res: list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.select_crop_app));
            builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    startActivityForResult(cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                }
            });

            builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null);
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
//==================== Take Picture
```

and also **CropOption** and **CropOptionAdapter** :

**CropOptionAdapter:**

```
public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions    = options;

        mInflater   = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon)).setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**CropOption:**

```
public class CropOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}
```

**Edited**
I am using gallery to crop, i was using "Bitmap photo" so it return small image, now using

File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());

f.getAbsolutePath()

but until sending image to server, it show **OutOfMemory** Error

That's new problem

Comment: "I am using default crop app in android devices" -- [there is no default crop app in Android devices](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) available for Android. Please use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of Memory Issue can be solved by fixing cropped/image from gallery  image to a fixed size. In onActivityResult include

```
    //Temp file to save cropped image
private String mImagePath;
private Uri mSaveUri = null;
private Uri mImageUri = null;
//File for capturing camera images
private File mFileTemp;

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(result.getData()); // Got the bitmap .. Copy it to the temp file for cropping
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFileTemp);
                copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
                fileOutputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                mImagePath = mFileTemp.getPath();
                mSaveUri = Utils.getImageUri(mImagePath);
                mImageUri = Utils.getImageUri(mImagePath);
                init();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errored();
            }

    private static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}



public class Utils {

public static Uri getImageUri(String path) {
    return Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
}
```

}

If you would like to use a custom libraries, I have created one and shared      in [GitHub](https://github.com/albinmathew/PhotoCrop)